# Flutter: Observatory server failed to start after x tries

Tags: flutter, dart

When I start the app, it starts the build and presents it in the log:

```
Installing build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk...                12,9s
I/flutter ( 8540): Observatory server failed to start after 1 tries
I/flutter ( 8540): Observatory server failed to start after 2 tries
I/flutter ( 8540): Observatory server failed to start after 3 tries
I/flutter ( 8540): Observatory server failed to start after 4 tries
I/flutter ( 8540): Observatory server failed to start after 5 tries
I/flutter ( 8540): Observatory server failed to start after 6 tries
I/flutter ( 8540): Observatory server failed to start after 7 tries
I/flutter ( 8540): Observatory server failed to start after 8 tries
I/flutter ( 8540): Observatory server failed to start after 9 tries
I/flutter ( 8540): Observatory server failed to start after 10 tries
I/flutter ( 8540): Observatory server failed to start after 11 tries
I/flutter ( 8540): Could not start Observatory HTTP server:
I/flutter ( 8540): SocketException: Failed to create server socket (OS Error: Operation not permitted, errno = 1), address = 127.0.0.1, port = 0
```

In this app, I consume an api, that api is running locally and I access it through my ip, 192.168.0.x: port
everything was working normally, and out of nowhere started giving this error, I already put and removed the 
androidManifest, I have no more ideas to do, any solution?

Comment: Do you have this in your manifest file? `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>`

Comment: Yes, I have.

I've tried without it, and with it

**android\app\src\profile\AndroidManifest.xml**

Comment: I was missing the \debug\AndroidManifest.xml file